# Different css style identifier in the html and style.css file in Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I want to add my blazor website into docker container. Everithing works properly but not in Docker. My css styles don't apply to the html page. I see that generated b-<10-character-string> differents between my html page and what we have in common style.css file. In production mode everything is work correctly (identifiers are the same) but in the docker it's not working.

In the html page:

```
<div class="home-title" b-n3ncg8cqqm="">
```

In the common style.css file:

```
.home-title[b-7foszch5y5] {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 150px;
    padding-top: 150px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 60px;
    line-height: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}
```

My Docker file:

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Logro.Server/Logro.Server.csproj", "Logro.Server/"]
COPY ["Logro.Domain/Logro.Domain.csproj", "Logro.Domain/"]
COPY ["Logro.Infastructure/Logro.Infrastructure.csproj", "Logro.Infastructure/"]
COPY ["Logro.Shared/Logro.Shared.csproj", "Logro.Shared/"]
COPY ["Logro.Client/Logro.Client.csproj", "Logro.Client/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Logro.Server/Logro.Server.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Logro.Server"
RUN dotnet build "Logro.Server.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Logro.Server.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Logro.Server.dll"]
```

My Docker compose file:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Docker
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - app-data:/app/Files
    depends_on:
      - mongo
  mongo:
    image: mongo:bionic
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - db-data:/data/db

volumes:
  db-data:
  app-data:
```

So we can see that in some reason identifier are differents but outside docker everything is work.

Comment: Post your Dockerfile or steps how you're building the dockerized app.

Comment: And when is this `b-<10 char string>` generated?

Comment: @StefanGolubović when the assembly takes place